# How calculate variable in SPSS using certain conditions?

Tags: syntax, spss

I have 7 variables:`(A,B,C,D,E,F,G)`. How  in menu `Transform-compute variable` in SPSS to summarize the variables whose value is equal to 1? I mean for example:

```
A=1
B=2
C=1
D=3
E=5
F=1
G=2
```

Here, only 3 vars have value 1. How to set a condition: sum if the value of the variable is equal to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value you asked for by using COUNT (in the TRANSFORM menu)  instead of COMPUTE. Counting how many of your variables have 1 in them will give the same result as summing them up.

If you want to define a more complicated condition, e.g. all values that are 1 or 2, you'll need to go to syntax and loop through your variables. Here's an example to get you started:

```
compute YourSum=0.
do repeat VR=A B C D E F G.
if VR=1 or VR=2 YourSum=YourSum+VR.
end repeat.
```

This loop goes through the variable list, and for each variable - if the value is 1 or 2, it is added to the sum.

Comment: Eli-k, tell me please. Is it possible to restructure the categories in spss. I have a few shops, but let's consider for example 2 shops (x, y)
Question:
There are many goods in this shop!
x (the answers of the respondents are binary - 0 or 1 agree in the column)
y.
In this shop  convenient service. 
x 0,1,0
y 0,1,0.
And so on. there are many other categories of questionnaires and the number of shops
I can make a frequency table, and then manually create a new dataset
like here

Comment: http://rgho.st/7YSVtDgXh (in xls)
Is it possible to use any formula or create via syntax,  the new dataset with needed format data like in my example
Did you understand my question?

Comment: eli-k, i want upvote your answer, but i can't do it, because i must have reputation >15, now only 11, when my rep be >15, i ll upvote. I promise

Comment: Funny, just noticed your comment above - this was your first question